# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/MessageConstraintException.class

Tags: android

I migrate my Android eclipse project to Android Studio project, but when I try to run my app it flags the following error--

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':wikiNews:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/MessageConstraintException.class
```

For more information below is my build.gradle file--

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.wikiNews"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':easyAndroidAnimationsLibrary')
    compile project(':liveSdk')
    compile project(':main')
    compile project(':zbarSample')
    compile project(':stickyHeaderLibrary')
    compile project(':starBar')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
    compile project(':socialNetworkingLib')
    /*compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'*/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    /*compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'*/

    /* compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'*/
    compile files('libs/nmdp_speech_kit.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
    compile files('libs/devsmartandroid.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-plus-v1-1.3.0-beta.jar')
   // compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.6.0-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.jar')
   // compile files('libs/thttpmime-4.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.2.jar')

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3')
            {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
}
```

Also please let me know if I can provide more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these dependencies in your gradle file :

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```

And dd this dependency in your gradle file :

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```